# How to stop a circular saw from locking?

Tags: tools, carpentry, powertools

I've been using my new circular saw for about a week. Today while making a plunge cut it just locked. It didn't get stuck on anything inside the board and it consistently locked every time I tried to cut something with it afterwards. Is there anything I can do about that other than invoke the warranty?

---

**Update**
Problem solved. The nut holding the blade down was coming loose. I'm new to power saws and didn't even think to check that. :/
Next problem. I tightened the nut as tight as it goes. Is it normal to have to do this after every single cut?

Comment: It's locking as you're making the cut?  Not locking up when it spins freely?

Comment: Try wearing gloves. It could be a safety lock that's designed to prevent you from slicing a finger. If the wood is damp, it could be transmitting the electrical charges that are detected by the saw.

Comment: @Bmitch the only safety stop I know of is the SawStop and that works by completely destroying your saw. Are there others on the market now?

Comment: @DA01, I was hoping that after 5 years, there would be. But alas, I can't find any.

Comment: Yea, the SawStop has an interesting history. Since the SawStop destroys the blade and saw itself, I'm guessing this isn't what's happening in this case. Sounds like a broken saw and/or it is binding on the substrate.

Comment: The SawStop system uses a replaceable cartridge that gets destroyed along with the blade, not the whole saw.  http://www.sawstop.com/wp-content/uploads/sawstop_whitepaper.pdf

Comment: The whole destroying the blade thing was the reason I decided against a Saw Stop. My wife changed her insistence on buying a Saw Stop when I pointed out that cutting slightly wet wood could cost $150 for the replacement cartridge and blade. I promised to be careful and use the blade guards whenever possible.

Comment: The Saw Stop is an amazing and great invention. Alas, it's being sold in a market where we tend to prioritize things via short term economics. ;) As for the follow up question, are you tightening the nut while the blade is locked? There's usually a way (such as a push-button) to lock the axle manually so you can tighten the nut properly.

Answer (score 1):

It is unusual to need to retighten the nut. If one side of the nut is concave, ensure that side is against the blade.